# Editing JSP files in Webstorm

Tags: jsp, webstorm

According to the configuration screen of the plugins, there is a Java Server Pages Integration plugin installed by default in WebStorm 5. The description of the plugins reads:

> Provides editing, code insight and refactoring support for JSP and JSPX files.

I created a project based on the source of an existing Java project, but none of what the description promises seems to work. When I open a .jsp file, the editor does not recognize any of the JSP specific tags and directives. The highlighting of the html and javascript content is correct, but because it does not understand JSP the entire file is full of errors. So is or is it not possible to edit .jsp files in Webstorm?

Answer (score 5):

JSP support is very limited as most of the JSP features would depend on Java support (which is not a part of WebStorm). For the complete JSP support consider IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate product, it has all the WebStorm features and much more.

Answer (score 0):

... what CrazyCoder said. Ultimate edition is well worth it (if you can splurge, for few more days they have good discount on personal license) Next best option (in terms of free editors) might be NetBeans. Not what you're asking about, but worth exploring.